# On discard changes, checkbox still having same state

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I am having a little problem that it's making headaches.

I have a modal where I show some info with checkboxes, the information, comes from an array, and I set the checkbox states from that array, and example of the array:

```
this.array = [
{scope: "acc", code: "1", alias: "aaa", selected: true, editable: true},
{scope: "acc", code: "2", alias: "bbb", selected: true, editable: true}
]
```

The thing that I want to do is to play as normal with the checks, but when i click a discardChanges button, the checkboxes, return the state that they were previously.

```
 <div *ngFor="let account of allAccountsList; let i = index;" class="">

          <div class="row">

              <input (click)="saveCheck(account.code, account.scope)" [(checked)]="account.selected"
                type="checkbox" name="genres" value="adventure" id="{{i}}">
              <label for="{{i}}" style="font-family: 'SExtralight'; font-size:14px;"></label>
            </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You need to make a copy of the "initial state" of the checkboxes (maybe on the hook OnInit of your modal cmponent), so once you press the discard change button, you know the previous values and it's possible to reset to the saved "initial state" with a for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
<div *ngFor="let account of array1; let i = index;">

    <input [checked]="account.selected"
                type="checkbox" 
                name="genres" 
                id="{{i}}">
    <label for="{{i}}" 
              style="font-size:14px;">{{ account.alias }}
    </label>
</div>
```

Does *not* update the `selected` property of the underlying array.

This code:

```
<div *ngFor="let account of array2; let i = index;">

    <input [(ngModel)]="account.selected"
                type="checkbox" 
                name="genres" 
                id="{{i}}">
    <label for="{{i}}" 
              style="font-size:14px;">{{ account.alias }}
    </label>
</div>
<div>
```

*Does* update the `selected` property of the underlying array.

Use the first set of code if you want to ensure that the underlying array data is not changed.

But if you do need to track the changes as the user clicks *and* allow for a discard changes option, use the second set of code. Then in the component, copy the array to keep the original values:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // Save a copy of the original values
    this.array2Copy = this.array2.map(e => ({...e}));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.array2Copy));
  }

  discardChanges() {
    // Copy the original values over the array
    this.array2 = this.array2Copy.map(e => ({...e}));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.array2Copy));
  }
```

I have a stackblitz of this code here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arraycopy-deborahk